# How can I link JavaScript to SVG?

Tags: javascript, svg, embed, xlink

I have a project that works with SVG and JS. Nowadays the SVG is responsible for calling the JS. In the middle of the SVG code there is an instruction like that:

planta30263.svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
....
<script type="text/javascript" xlink:href="tatu1/svgEditarVisualizacao.js"     xlink:actuate="onLoad" xlink:show="other" xlink:type="simple" />
.....
```

However sometimes it's necessary to change the directory from one server to another. (tatu1 -> tatu2) So, I'd like to know if there is a way to make JS calls the SVG in the page which SVG is embedded, an external calling.

vis_rota.jsp

```
....
<embed  src="<%=planta%>" id="plantaSVG" type="image/svg+xml" name="plantaSVG" />
....
```

Answer (score 1):

The xlink:actuate, xlink:show and xlink:type attributes on the script element are not necessary, you can safely remove them.

It's better to use `<object>` rather than `<embed>` because then you can then provide fallback content if a browser lacks the ability to display svg, or if it has been disabled for any reason. For more information see the [SVG Primer](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#SVG_in_HTML).

If you want to call functions from the svg to the document that referenced it, then see [scripting between svg and html](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#scripting_HTML) for some examples.

Comment: Just adding what I extracted from your link: calling external javascript functions works with `onclick="top.myJSFunc()"` with the emphasis on **top.** prefixing the function.

Comment: Well, you'd use `top` if you needed the topmost document yes. You can use `parent` to get the closest parent document - here's an example: http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/html/from-svg-to-parent-html-script.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want and a plug but
 at [iscriptdesign](http://www.iscriptdesign.com) you can see some javascript manupulation to view different svg images. Adapt images online, and upload them using html 5's  file api.

Comment: Looking a bit more closely, i think you're looking for a hook upon the embed to intercept and manipulate the svg/javascript code. If